# How to get started with bash?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, bash-script

I need a way to be able to run a script that will automate terminal commands, one after another. As I understand it, this is exactly what bash does. (Am I right, even on this count?)

Where can I learn, basically, how to set them up?

Also, how can I make one run at startup?

PS Are the shell and the terminal/command line the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Where can I learn, basically, how to set them up?

For setting up a script which executes commands, just create a file (e.g. `MyCmds.sh`) with your editor and write some commands, which you want to execute. E.g.:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This is a quote, the next line will output "Hello World"
echo "Hello World"
```

Now you need to make this file executable by setting the `x` flag (use your terminal for this):

```
$ chmod +x MyCmds.sh
```

Now you can run it like this in your terminal (do not forget the leading `./`):

```
$ ./MyCmds.sh
```

You should see `Hello World`.

> Also, how can I make one run at startup?

To run this script at startup, you have to put the commands, or your script with the absolut path (e.g. `/path/to/my/script/MyCmds.sh`), into the textfile `/etc/rc.local` (There is sometimes an `exit 0` at the end, your commands have be above that line).

> PS Are the shell and the terminal/command line the same?

Yes (and maybe No). I assume that you mean the normal command line where you type in your commands and the with shell the sripts, am I right?
It always depends on your setup. If you run a script with `#!/bin/bash` (the first two signes are called `shebang`) in the 
first line, every following line will be passed to the shell-program located at `/bin/bash`. What you see as your command line is maybe `/bin/bash` or `/bin/shell` or `...` (They differ by their features). You can check this by looking at the file `/etc/passwd`. After your linux username there should stand the program for your command line.

Comment: Does the `#` symbol represent a comment? If so, why is the `!/bin/bash` commented out?

Comment: Yes and No. The first line is an exception. The two signes `#!` (called `shebang`) introduce the programm for the interpretation of the script. In my case, it is `/bin/bash`. You can also run python code like this by writing `#!/usr/bin/python` in the first line, and then some `print('Hello World')` into the next line.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to recommend:
http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html

It walks you through anything from very basics (goes from hello world example) to more advanced constructions, and it is a part of the The Linux Documentation Project.

Comment: This is the best resource for getting started with bash!

Comment: yeah - only used the TLDP for bash almost :-)

Comment: Actually this is much more thorough for a 'starter', same site but different entry :-) http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/

Answer (score 3):

`bash` is a shell, or commandline interpreter.  A shell script is a text file containing a list of commands to be executed by a given shell (comparable to a batch file, if you are familiar with that parlance).

A shell script can use any commandline interpreter (or shell) its author wishes to use by specifying it on the first line.  For example, if a given script uses `bash`, its first line will typically look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

This would then be followed by a list of commands (generally speaking) just as you'd type them, in order, at an interactive shell.

With regard to your post scriptum:  not *quite*.  The shell (or commandline interpreter) is the program that handles the parsing of command lines, which are the things you enter, either interactively or into a script as described above.

Answer (score 3):

There are numerous ways to get going but here is what I recommend you do:

1. Make a directory to store your scripts:

   ```
   mkdir ~/bin
   ```
2. Edit your ~/.bashrc ( I assume you know how to handle an editor), and add at the bottom:

   ```
   if [ -d ~/bin ] ; then
      export PATH=~/bin:"${PATH}"
   fi
   ```
3. Logout and login again (or start a new terminal) and check if `~/bin` is in your path:

   ```
   echo $PATH
   ```
4. Create your first program `~/bin/echo_on_boot` and put in

   ```
   #! /bin/bash
   echo "Started" > /var/tmp/written_on_startup
   ```
5. change the permissions on the program so it will execute:

   ```
   chmod 750 ~/bin/echo_on_boot
   ```
6. try the program:

   ```
   echo_on_boot
   ```
7. check if `/var/tmp/written_on_startup` was created and delete it:

   ```
   cat /var/tmp/written_on_startup
   rm -f /var/tmp/written_on_startup
   ```
8. edit your crontab with `crontab -e`, add a line (near the bottom usually), assuming that `~` is `/home/vamvid` (you cannot use `~` in the crontab file):

   ```
    @reboot /home/vamvid/bin/echo_on_boot
   ```
9. reboot the system and see if the file is created in /var/tmp.

`@reboot` will not work if you home directory is e.g. on an encrypted drive as the `~/bin` directory is then not available after reboot (only when you login).