# Resources to learn shell scripting

Tags: shell

I have been using GNU/Linux for sometime now (Ubuntu and Fedora) and now I am trying to learn shell scripting from scratch. I need to choose the right documentation/links to start off with.

**PS:** I can create simple scripts and can understand slightly complex ones.

ed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learned scripting with these Guides:

[Bash Beginners Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/index.html)

Topics include:

1. Bash environment
2. regex
3. awk
4. sed
5. interactive scripts
6. loops + shift
7. functions
8. signals
9. more...

[Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/)

Topics include:

1. Basics + convention Quoting, Exit status
2. Variable maniulation
3. Commands (builtins, filters, sysadm)
4. regex
5. i/o redirection
6. process substitution
7. subshells
8. more...

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for web resources I've found [this](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) to be helpful for most of my uses.

Answer (score 1):

You should find [Heiner's SHELLdorado](http://www.shelldorado.com/) a good starting point.  Don't underestimate the manpages as an on-going resource, either, as you develop code.

Comment: Sure..Will go Through them..:)

Answer (score 0):

Try getting these books: Classic Shell Scripting and bash Cookbook. They are both by O'Reilly. There is also tons of documentations and youtube videos online.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a post similar to this, where i answered the same as Livinglifeback with the tldp bash documentation. There was also some other great ones. Here is the link: [How to get started with bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111797/how-to-get-started-with-bash/111817#111817).