# Shell scripting enthusiast

Tags: shell-script

This may sound generic and non technical to many but i can use some quality advice here. I am an technical support engineer who happens to be interested in shell scripting. My job does not need me to code and i need some advice on how i can develop my self as a shell scripting resource as i would like to make scripting / programing  as one of the competency for future roles. I am already working on simple scrips using cent os and VMware. Any advice will be appreciated!

Comment: Try answering shell questions here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resources to learn shell scripting](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138038/resources-to-learn-shell-scripting)

Comment: Also just code more, maybe read some scripts that are out there to learn how they work. And follow Stephane's suggestion, learn by teaching others ;).

Answer (score 3):

Basic Bash reference you can find here:

- Bash [reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) on GNU.org

There are a lot of interesting ideas in tutorials and examples, so do your search or follow these:

- Bash examples in three parts on IBM.com 
  [part1](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-bash/index.html) [part2](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-bash2/index.html) [part3](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-bash3/index.html)
- BASH Programming - [Introduction](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html) HOW-TO, on tldp.org

there are many [links](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/tutoriallist) to tutorials on long term sites like this listed on wiki.bash-hackers.org :

- http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/tutoriallist

[image]

- Also take into account that many programmers on Stack Exchange(SE) often include links to their blogs (where they often post bash scripts examples) form their profiles on SE.